# Instagram comments API can't add 'text' value

Tags: ios, instagram

My requested URL is `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/MYMEDIA_ID/comments?access_token=MYTOKEN&text=MYTEXT`

I get a reply like this:

```
{
    meta =     {
        code = 400;
        "error_message" = "Missing 'text'";
        "error_type" = APIInvalidParametersError;
    };
}
```

In the Instagram document it says the comment API takes two parameters: `text` and `access_token`. I have provided both, and I get the error saying `text` is missing.

I have tried with different symbols instead of `&` but nothing works. Does anybody have experience on how the `text` parameter should appear on the requested URL?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

i am using hybridauth, and here is the code, it is working..

```
function setUserComment($post_id, $message)
{
    $flag = 0;  
    $parameters = array("text" => $message);
    $response  = $this->api->post( "media/$post_id/comments", $parameters );    

    // check the last HTTP status code returned
    if ( $this->api->http_code != 200 ){
        throw new Exception( "Comment failed! {$this->providerId} returned an error. " . $this->errorMessageByStatus( $this->api->http_code ) );
    }
    else{
        $flag = 1;
    }
    return $flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add comments to Instagram you need to post the text it shouldn't be part of the URL. The Instagram API documentation provides an example using CURL:

```
curl -F 'access_token=1084932.f59def8.deb7db76ffc34f96bada217fe0b6cd9a' \
     -F 'text=This+is+my+comment' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments
```

So neither the access_token or the text are part of the URL just POST data.

Comment: thanks, but i was able to solve the problem by putting 'text' as htmlBody of the httpRequest. was able to put access_token in the URL though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add text=MYTEXT to your request's HTTPBody.

Here is sample code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:apiURL];
apiRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text=%@", MYTEXT] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
apiRequest.HTTPBody = body;

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:apiRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // Handle the response.
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the content type of the request ContentType="comment"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key here is ContentType header. At least nothing worked for me until I started to define it.

If you set "ContentType": "multipart/form-data" you need to set up quite a complex body content as described here:
https://dotnetthoughts.net/post-requests-from-azure-logic-apps/

I found much easier path:
Set your header "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

and then you can set your request body as simple as key=url_escaped(value):
text=My%20comment